# Find angles of polygon using only known distances

Tags: geometry, polygon, trigonometry, mesh

I've got a mesh of points, but simplified I've got 5 points with 2 being primary points.

All distances from A and B to any other points are known ( C, D, E ), but the distance from A and B is not known. Neither are the location of these points, only the distances. Although A can be considered the origin (0,0).

Is it possible to find the internal angles and then consequently the distance between point A and B.
Otherwise how would this scenario need to be modified in order to find this distance.
Or is there simply just not enough information known?

[image: Diagram]

The actual scenario can have more points with distances from points A and B known, but I've just tried to simplify here.

Comment: Insufficient data. In your diagram you could pull points A and B further apart and the other points would move accordingly, keeping the same line lengths. To nail it down, you would need to know at least one angle, for example, at E.

Comment: Yeah I can see that now, I'm aware that this may be just complicating the matter, but would it be solvable with the addition of a third reference point knowing the distance to the previous three.
ie [http://i.imgur.com/AF9suiZ.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/AF9suiZ.jpg)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mathematics. Try http://math.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: there is no way to tel if your points are above or under the AB line ...

Answer (score 0):

No. Lets fix `A` at (0,0) and `B` along the horizontal axis. Each two leg pair `ACB`, `AEB` and `ADB` can flex its elbow joint to allow for any position of `B` along the horizontal axis.

Given an `AB` distance then all the angles and points are uniquely defined. But if `AB` is unknown then the shape can fold on itself.